# AppDistribution Gradle plugin with Gradle 7

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-app-distribution

I am using Android Gradle Plugin version `7.0.0-alpha14` and Gradle version `7.0` and when I try to upload the app to app distribution through the Gradle plugin version `2.1.0` it fails on a task `app:appDistributionUploadDebug` with an error

```
> Task :app:appDistributionUploadDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:appDistributionUploadDebug' (type 'UploadDistributionTask').
  - Type 'UploadDistributionTask' property 'COMMAND_LINE_PREFIX' is missing an input or output annotation.
    
    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - Type 'UploadDistributionTask' property 'appDistributionProperties' is missing an input or output annotation.
    
    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
```

I suppose the plugin is not compatible with Gradle 7 but is it a known issue and is there some workaround? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Did you have any luck fixing this?

Comment: @PhilippMaksimov Hey, no, according to Firebase developers they have it tracked in internal system and there is currently no workaround, reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2580

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New version of plugin `2.1.1` was released that fixes this issue.

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.1.1'
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Goto project's `build.gradle` file
2. Add below line into dependencies block :-

   **classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18'**

[image]